# [Hadoop]: Error while building on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am currently trying to build hadoop 2.7.2 for windows 8.1 x64 Plateform. I am following instruction from https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows .

I am getting an error for Apache Hadoop Common Project while building using following maven command  `mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar`. Following is error

```
"C:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
(Link target) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/bin/hadoop.dll' [C:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.